# Notice: array to string conversion in preg_replace php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following find (from mongodb) field working well but when I try to use the preg_replace, I get the following error message

> Notice: array to string conversion in ...

My code:

```
$mongorow = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id))); //finds based on ID
$dotodot  = preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", $mongorow);
```

Comment: Try: `$dotodot = preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", implode('', $mongorow));`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that **$mongorow** is an array and you are treating it like a string or a variable.

it should be:

```
$dotodot = preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", $mongorow['_id']);
```

Comment: pls how do i treat it as an array, I just need to replace the value everywhere it exists in the array. sorry i'm a bit new to this :)

Comment: if i do: $dotodot = preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", $mongorow['_id']); no error message but i think it's searching id fields. the field I plan on making these changes is:  $dotodot = preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", $mongorow['properties']);

Comment: i think the issue is that the field pattern exists in is a hash field. how can i convert this to string please?

Answer (score 0):

`findOne()` returns an array (or NULL if search failed), so you'll have to first get the field out of your result before you treat it as a String.

```php
$str = $mongorow['whateverYouWereLookingFor'];
$dotodot = preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", $str);
```

Edit: If you need to replace across a whole array, you want to look at the `array_map()` function.

Comment: by $str = $mongorow['whateverYouWereLookingFor'];? is 'whateverYouWereLookingFor' referring to the field I wish to make the replacement in?

Answer (score 0):

`$mongorow` is an array. The function pref_replace does not accept an array as second parameter. You need to check the values of the array and check which one you need to use. Select that so called array value like `$mongorow['value']`.

If you are not introduced to arrays yet, don't hesitate to read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) page.

Comment: First and second parameters in preg_replace can be both string or array.